# How do I get a list of quarantined mail through EWS?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to be able to get a list of quarantined mail through EWS, forca certain mail address. Is it possible, and how?

Is it possible to use to use event sink? It would also be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EWS doesn't provide access to quarantined mail. What version of Exchange are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it in EWS, but if you have access to EMS (Exchange Management Shell) you can do the following. The 'if' statement code is optional, but would send you an email if it finds any quarantined mailboxes. This is handy if used as part of a scheduled task in task scheduler.

```
#START OF SCRIPT

$Quarantined = $null

$ServerList = "server1", "server2"

foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
{
$Quarantined += Get-MailboxStatistics -Server $Server | Where-Object {$_.IsQuarantined -eq $true} | ft displayname
}

if ($Quarantined -ne $null)
{
Send-MailMessage -Body ($Quarantined | Out-String) -Subject "EXCHANGE Alert - Quarantined Mailbox" -From exchange@contoso.com -To itgroup@contoso.com -SmtpServer mail.contoso.com
}

# END OF SCRIPT
```

Failing that you could just run this one liner;

```
Get-MailboxStatistics -Server 'server' | Where-Object {$_.IsQuarantined -eq $true} | ft displayname
```